# LDAP connections favoring 1 DC over the other in same site

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, ldap

Observing spikes in "AD Search Subops" counter and "PROC LSASS%" counter daily on DC A relative to DC B; its not in maintainence windows; its at start of business hrs daily.

-> Eliminated the point of hardcoding because, one time for brief moment of time DC A went down and there was spike in DC B, which means the connections know how to go to a different DC but are choosing not to.
-> My question is, can it be something wrong with link-cost stuff(unlikely since both DC's are in same site), is there some setting which makes LDAP connections go to 1 DC in rather than taking random approach?
-> Both DC's are 2008 R2's.

Appolozize if details are few, please ask me if anything required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by "Domain Controller Stickiness" and causes the clients to prefer one domain controller over another.

You can adjust this by forcing the clients to choose another controller at intervals. The GP setting is under `Administrative Templates\System\Net Logon\DC Locator DNS Records\ Entry Name: Force Rediscovery Interval.`

This setting should reduce load on your DC by balancing out the clients more. As a rule, it's a first come, first serve with DCs so whichever answers gets the client.

Comment: Client can be anything, so you are suggesting modify default domain controller policy; is it worth for an issue with single site and 2 DC's?

Comment: If the load is too high on a single DC it may be worth a try. The alternative is to beef up the affected DC with some more resources.